# Jemeter test JDBC param

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

This is ThreadGroup:
[image: this is ThreadGroup]

This is JDBC Connection Config:
![this is JDBC CONNECTIIN CONFIG][2]

The SQL:

```
 SELECT siteid FROM tky_tab_bbsdata WHERE name = ?
```

And then it throws exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: 并非所有变量都已绑定
>   the request is :SELECT siteid FROM tky_tab_bbsdata where name = ?
>   梁段
>   VARCHAR

I don't know how to solve this problem, the SQL may be right!

Comment: Please provide your JDBC Connection Configuration

Comment: JDBC Connection Configuration may be no problem  , I check the table by "select * from table" that it has no problems , but I use placeholder it happens   SQLException: ORA-01008: 并非所有变量都已绑定

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use parameter outside SQL statement:

Remove values from: parameter values and parameter type

In SQL statement replace your `= ?` with a real value, use `= '[value]'`

Comment: user real value it has no problem , use placeholder it happens SQLException: ORA-01008: 并非所有变量都已绑定

Comment: Did you remove parameter values and parameter type and update your sql to ... name ='[your value]'